# Why is my Hamburger menu not in right(mobile)?

Tags: css, flexbox, developer-tools

The hamburger menu is not on the right side when I use my mobile phone. However, when I use developer tools it is on the right side. I cannot figure out why is this happening.

**Developer tools:**

[image]

**Mobile Phone:**

[image]

**CODE:**

```
<nav className="nav-menu-mobile">
  <div className="hamburger-container">
    <Hamburger toggled={isOpen} toggle={setIsOpen} />
  </div>

  (Codes for Link Menus)
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-menu-mobile {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;

  z-index: 3;
}

.hamburger-container {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100vw;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;

  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

@media (min-width: 655px) {
  .nav-menu-mobile {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you can set `justify-content: flex-end;` and it might fix the issue.

```
.hamburger-container {
justify-content: flex-end;
-webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
}
```